# Words from text file as variables in a checkedlistbox

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have discovered how to take a text file and put it in an checkedlistbox. Now I want to apply variables to each item in the checkedlistbox also using a text file.

This is the code I used.

```
Imports System.IO 'Top of the source code
 Dim sr As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.txt")
    Dim word As String = ""
    Dim words(9) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until sr.Peek = -1
        word = sr.ReadLine()
        words(i) = word
        Vlanbx1.Checklisbox.Items.Add(words(i))
        Vlanbx2.Checklisbox.Items.Add(words(i))

        i = i + 1

    Loop
```

I would like to have both the checkedlistbox items and the variables in the same text file side by side.

My main goal is to have a list that when it is changed in the text file is updates when the form is opened. But I am unsure how to grab the variables to the text and apply them to their adjacent Items from the list.

Any guidance, please.

Comment: What problem do you have with this code?

Comment: @Steve The code is fine. It was an example of what I used to pull the text file words into the checkedlistbox. Apologies for the confusion. I was mostly using it as an reference to see if I can use it to pull the variables and assign it to the correlation items in the checkedlistbox.

Comment: Well you are doing it correctly. Every item in the checkedlistbox is initialized from the value that you read from the file and before adding the item you save the line in an element of your array. The only thing that need to be changed is the use of a fixed size array. If you have more than 10 lines your code will crash. Use a List(Of string) instead

Comment: @Steve So if I have two columns words in a text file what would be the best way to grab the first column as the list to go into the checkedlistbox and then the second column my variable. I think I can apply the variables to the Items in the list by saying some like array1 item 0 = array2 item 0 and so forth I am just unsure where to start my research or find an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works without problem only if your file has no more that 10 lines.
You could change it in this way

```
Imports System.IO 
....
Dim words = File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.txt").ToList()
For Each word in words
    Vlanbx1.Checklisbox.Items.Add(word)
    Vlanbx2.Checklisbox.Items.Add(word)
Next
```

Now the File.ReadLines returns all the lines of your file in a `List(Of String)` then you could loop over this List and add the words one by one to your CheckedListBoxes

**EDIT**
Following your comment, if you have a line composed of two words separated by a space and the first word should be stored in the checkedlistbox while the second one in a internal list of words, then your code should change to

```
Imports System.IO 
....
Dim listOfSecondWords = new List(Of String)()
Dim lines = File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.txt").ToList()
For Each line in lines
    Dim words = line.Split(" "c)
    Vlanbx1.Checklisbox.Items.Add(words(0))
    Vlanbx2.Checklisbox.Items.Add(words(0))
    listOfSecondWords.Add(words(1))
Next
```

A bit of error control should be added to be really sure that you have two words for each line checking the length of the array `words` obtained splitting the line at the first space character